# Verification of the translation of English sentences into predicate logic.

Tags: proof-verification, logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers, logic-translation

I want to translate some sentences into predicate logic [based off the text "Language, Proof and Logic" (Barwise, Etchemendy) 1st ed].

The sentences are as follows:

1. Only in front of large objects is nothing.
2. Each tetrahedron is in front of all dodecahedra.
3. No tetrahedron is the exact same size as a cube.
4. Every small cube is to the left of a large tetrahedron.
5. there is a large tetrahedron which lies to the right of every cube.
6. nothing is behind a cube.

I have formulated **solutions** and tested them using the program Tarski's World using worlds in which I expect the sentences to be true and worlds in which I expect the sentences to be false.

1. $\forall x ( Large(x) \to \neg \exists y \ FrontOf(y,x))$
2. $\forall x \forall y \ ((Tet(x) \land Dodec(y)) \to FrontOf(x,y))$
3. $\neg \exists x \ (Tet(x) \land \exists y (Cube(y) \land SameSize(x,y)))$
4. $\forall x \ ((Small(x) \land Cube(x)) \to \exists y (Large(y) \land Tet(y) \land LeftOf(x,y)))$
5. $\forall x \ (Cube(x) \to \exists y \ (Tet(y) \land Large(y) \land RightOf(y,x)))$
6. $\exists x \ (Cube(x) \to \neg \exists y \ BackOf(y,x)) $

Could anyone please verify that the sentences are correct/have been sensibly formulated? Does anyone have alternative suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 6 is not correct. Now, as dxiv points out in the comments, 6 actually has two different interpretations, but your translation does not capture either of them.

The first reading of 6 is:

"There is a cube with nothing behind it".

In logic, this would be:

$$\exists x (Cube(c) \land \neg \exists y \ BackOf(y,x))$$

The second reading is:

"Nothing is behind any cube"

which translates as:

$$\neg \exists x (Cube(x) \land \exists y \ BackOf(y,x))$$

Note in both cases you get a $\land$ in combination with an $\exists$ ... this is what very often* happens when you translate into first-order logic: $\forall$'s tend to go hand in hand with $\rightarrow$, while $\exists$'s tend to go with $\land$'s .. this is not a strict rule, but many English sentences, when translated, end up as such. Indeed, this is how I immediately spotted your mistake for $6$: I just scanned for those combinations, and when I saw your $\exists$ together with a $\rightarrow$, I knew there was a good chance your translation was wrong.

Answer (score 3):

> > Only in front of large objects is nothing.
>
> $∀x~(\operatorname{Large}(x)\to\lnot \exists y~\operatorname{FrontOf}(y,x))$

I am translating this as: "In front of all large objects **is** *only* nothing".

That is not the same as saying "*Only* **in front** of large objects is nothing," which is that "Something is in front of all not-large objects."

$$\forall x~(\neg\operatorname{Large}(x)\to\exists y~\operatorname{FrontOf}(y,x))$$

This may just be the way that I parse the sentence, but the adverb "only" does seem to modify the placement rather than the existance.

---

I have no disagreements with the others.  They seem fine to me.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the ambiguity of casual English. Same goes for #6 which I would tend to read as "*nothing is behind* ***any*** *cube*" rather than "*there exists* ***a*** *cube behind which is nothing*".